# Not able to login into LDAP with Fr3d LDAP Bundle (Register works)

Tags: symfony, fr3dldapbundle

I'm struggling with implementing Fr3d LDAP Bundle (with FOSUserbundle) into Symfony.
I came that far as being able to login for the first time and getting registered in the database.
Though now I got the problem that I can't login a second time. It just throws "bad username and password". Here are my configs:

config.yml

```
fos_user:
   db_driver: orm
   firewall_name: main
   user_class: example\AcmeBundle\Entity\User

fr3d_ldap:
   driver:
      host: ldap.example.de
      port: 389
      useSsl: false;

user:
    baseDn: ou=people, dc=example, dc=de
    attributes:
      - { ldap_attr: uid,  user_method: setUsername }
      - { ldap_attr: mail,  user_method: setEmail }
    filter: (objectClass=*)
```

Security.yml

```
security:
   firewalls:
      main:
         pattern: ^/
         fr3d_ldap: ~
         form_login:
           always_use_default_target_path: true
           default_target_path: /profile
           provider: chain_provider
         logout:       true
         anonymous:    true

   providers:
      chain_provider:
        chain:
          providers: [fos_userbundle, fr3d_ldapbundle]
      fr3d_ldapbundle:
          id: fr3d_ldap.security.user.provider    
      fos_userbundle:
          id: fos_user.user_manager    

  encoders:
     example\AcmeBundle\Entity\User : plaintext

  access_control:
      - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
      - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

  role_hierarchy:
      ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
      ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

I searched and tried everything I could find on the net, but since nearly all of the documentation is pretty old I couldn't find anything.

**EDIT**
Actually a colleague of mine just found the answer.

For our LDAP to recognize the user you need to supply the bind with the uid via "uid=". We solved the problem now by giving the filter another argument which looks like this:

```
user:
    baseDn: ou=people, dc=example, dc=de
    attributes:
      - { ldap_attr: uid,  user_method: setUsername }
      - { ldap_attr: mail,  user_method: setEmail }
    filter: (&(objectClass=Person)(uid=%s))
```

I'm sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Weird because the LdapManager adds automatically the uid. Can you try to the same but with quotes? `baseDn: "ou=people, dc=example, dc=de"` & `filter: "(objectClass=*)"`

Comment: @Maks3w Just tried that, but I still get the same error. It doesn't seem to work with your solution :(

Comment: Really weird, maybe is something related with the wildcard because in my test I was using (objectClass=IntPerson) without problems. If you or your friend find the source bug please send a PR to the project